# WPF - find actual top and left of an image after rotating it

Tags: wpf, rotatetransform

I am using WPF and I have an image of an 8.5" * 11" piece of paper on a Canvas.  I am then rotating the image using a RotateTransform, with the axis being in the middle of the page (that is, RotateTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5").  How can I find the actual location on the canvas of the corners of the image?

Comment: One idea is to use PointToScreen and then you will always have the location of the top and left of then you can manually calculate the new top and left from actual width and height

Answer (score 1):

http://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080607033505AAF75UC

(this is the geometry way)

Answer (score 0):

```
_image.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), _canvas);
```

Will this do?